# How to address 4x SDRAM chips with only two CS signals exposed on edge connector?

Tags: sdram

I'm trying to build a system to test memory modules built around 512 Mbit SDRAM chips by reading/writing to chips individually. As you can see in the attached schematic, CS0 and CS1 are shared between the upper and lower chips. On the target system (host of these memory modules) the CPU has 29 address signals + 32-bit data bus. DQM lines also are unique for each chip. (actual module uses 512 Mbit SDRAM)

[image: SDRAM memory module]
The system I'm trying to build is based on STM32F429. SDRAM controller offers two banks (two unique NEs + CKEs) with 4 internal banks each. The data bus signals DQ[0..15], address signals A[0..12], BA0/1, CAS/RAS/CLK, are going to be shared on my design for all chips. However, I'm still uncertain on how to enable only one chip at a time so I can perform reading/writing tests of a single chip to test the integrity of the memory module.

I believe on the original host system that uses these memory modules, the memory is accessed by switching lower and upper address lanes, so they only exposed two CS lines.

What is the most feasible way to do it?

Perhaps some external glue logic, address decoder, mux, or use 16-bit buffer for address lines so that I can enable/disable lower/upper address signals at will?